# Doesn't Azure AD B2C Page UI Customization Support Bootstrap?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to customize the page UI on Azure AD B2C unified sign in/sign up page.

I was able to create my template and upload all the assets i.e. html page, images and css to my Azure Blob Storage container with the right `CORS` settings.

When I pull up the page, however, it looks **absolutely HORRIBLE!** It doesn't seem to support Bootstrap. I read somewhere that no JavaScript is allowed. Is that the reason for this?

Once I upload my custom HTML page, Azure AD B2C seems to be stripping off a lot of the design elements necessary for my customization such as `id` and `style` in my `body` tag -- see below:

```
<!-- Omitted for brevity -->
<body id="my-login-class" style="url: ('https://myazurestorage.blob.core.windows.net/my-container/my-bg-image.jpg')">

   <div id="some-important-id" class="my-important-class">
      <div class="col-xs-8">
          <div>Some important message</div>
      <div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
         <div id="api">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

</body>
```

When I inspect the page source once my custom page is rendered, I see that all my classes and Id's are removed along with Bootstrap references e.g. `css` and `js`.

Am I getting this right? No Bootstrap which means Azure AD B2C only supports customization of the most basic kind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your HTML template can include any external, `head`, or inline styles but it can't include scripts.

An example of a customized page can be found at [the WoodGrove sign-up or sign-in page](https://woodgroveb2c.b2clogin.com/b3c3aa0d-d4db-459d-8bf6-ed1538d45256/b2c_1_sign_up_sign_in_personal/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=dc6734e7-45ec-4845-a2b1-ed4ca3be6035&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwoodgrovegroceriesb2c.azurewebsites.net%2Fb2c-signin-callback&response_type=id_token&scope=openid&response_mode=form_post&nonce=defaultNonce).

The HTML template for this customized page can be found in [the WoodGrove GitHub repository](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-external-identities-woodgrove-demo/tree/master/Templates).

This HTML template includes [Bootstrap's Reboot styles](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/reboot/) as well as the WoodGrove's specific styles.

Azure AD B2C creates the `head` and `body` elements and then copies the child elements for each of these `head` and `body` elements from your HTML template to its HTML document.

Therefore, you shouldn't add attributes to the `body` element in your HTML template, because they aren't copied.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I was able to get it to work. So, there’s no way for me read some user data that I save in localStorage for returning users?

Comment: No, currently, JavaScript isn't supported.

Comment: I understand the potential security risks involved but I hope the Azure AD team will figure out a secure way to add JS support soon. It can really open the way to create powerful experiences for users. I happen to have a pretty cool UI for login/signup but just because I can’t access the localStorage, my UX is already degraded.

Comment: FYI, [UserVoice to allow JS in B2C](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15493536-add-support-for-javascript-inside-the-custom-ui-br) @Sam

Comment: This is GREAT! I was looking into forcing metronic to make my azure b2c login more appealing but it was a hassle. So good to see an OS initiative to do this!

Answer (score 1):

You can import the bootstrap references. Please see this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/azure-ad-b2c

See also: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-php-webapp-openidconnect

Comment: What about my `id`'s and `class`'es being removed from DOM elements such as the `<body id="my-id" class="some-class">` tag?

Comment: Without using class names, I was able to customize the body. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks horrible for a reason. No styling is applied to the page so that it can be fully customizable. You can reference Bootstrap for CSS; however, I have run in to issues when using bootstrap.js for modals since it appears the Azure B2C API uses bootstrap for modals...In my experience, it is best to rely on Vanilla JS and to leave off any references to third-party JS.

It is possible to use JavaScript if you are using your own custom policies. There are [some limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#guidelines-for-using-javascript) to JavaScript and the best approach is to try to accomplish anything using the policy first.

To enable JavaScript use the following as guide:

```
<RelyingParty>
   <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
   <UserJourneyBehaviors>
     <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
   </UserJourneyBehaviors>
 ...
</RelyingParty>
```

When referencing external CSS/JS files, the URL must be absolute. This is true for the head section of HTML files as well as any references within JavaScript. Relative URL's can only be referenced within a CSS file.

Incorrect:

```
<link href="./css/assets.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Correct:

```
<link href="https://your-storage-account.blob.core.windows.net/your-container/css/assets.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```